# Convert list collection into Dictionary for performance c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an excel sheet with some rows. Alongside, I have a db table that has the same definition as the excel sheet in terms of column structure. What I want to do is check if a record exists in the excel sheet but not in the db table then insert it into a new table (an  existing empty table) called `TableReport` for reporting purposes.

CSV File: **PathToFile.csv**

Original table to do comparison on: **FruitTable**

New table created for reporting: **TableReport**

The following code snippets are what you can use to test my scenario. The code below **works** as I am using a `List<T>` when `PathToFile.csv` is relatively quite small- As in like 4 rows. Takes under 30 seconds to complete execution of the program. However my real scenario involves `PathToFile.csv` have about 200 000 rows and thus the list collection is not so efficient in terms of performance. Thus, I have considered using a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` collection but I am stuck as to which parts within the code to tweak because with both collections, I will have to iterate the entire csv to get all the rows and add the to the `checkIfFruitsMatch` list in this case. Even if I use a dictionary, I would still need to loop and add them before I even perform the comparision and already that is time consuming. Performance is a very critical requirement in this case.

I tried running the program with my current implementation of the list on a csv with 200 000 rows and it took well over 15 minutes, busy looping through the csv and adding the rows to the list and that didn't even finish before I terminated the program.

How can I achieve this to make the program much more faster. It shouldn't take longer than 10 minutes to execute. I have written this in a Windows Forms Application.

**SQL Table Definition:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FruitTable](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Apples] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Oranges] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Pears] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Bananas] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [DateAddedUtc] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**Stored Procedure Definition:**

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[spAddFruitsToDB]
@Apples [nvarchar](20),
@Oranges [nvarchar](20),
@Pears [nvarchar](20),
@Bananas [nvarchar](20),
@DateAddedUtc [nvarchar](50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableReport --Has the same definition as FruitTable
    VALUES (@Apples, @Oranges, @Pears, @Bananas, @DateAddedUtc)
END
```

**Code:**

```
    public class FruitClass {

            private SqlConnection mySQLConnection;
            private SqlCommand mySQLCommand;
            private SqlDataReader mySQLDataReader;
            private string myConnectionString;

        private void CheckDataValidity()
        {   
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel_app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks work_books = Excel_app.Workbooks;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook work_book = work_books.Open("C:\\PathToFile.csv");

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets work_sheets = work_book.Worksheets;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet work_sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)work_sheets.get_Item(1);

            List<FruitClass> checkIfFruitsMatch = new List<FruitClass>();
            List<FruitClass> dbFruitsToMatch= new List<FruitClass>();
            string fruitTagNumberForApples = "";

            for (int j = 2; j < work_sheet.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                FruitClass fruitInstance = new FruitClass();
                fruitInstance.Apples = CellToString(work_sheet.Cells[j, 3]).Trim();
                fruitInstance.Oranges = CellToString(work_sheet.Cells[j, 13]).Trim();
                fruitInstance.Pears = CellToString(work_sheet.Cells[j, 14]).Trim();
                fruitInstance.Bananas = CellToString(work_sheet.Cells[j, 15]).Trim();

                fruitTagNumberForApples = fruitInstance.Apples;

                checkIfFruitsMatch.Add(fruitInstance);

                if (fruitTagNumberForApples == null || fruitTagNumberForApples == "" || fruitTagNumberForApples == string.Empty)
                break;
            }

            //Get fruits in excel and do a comparison with fruits in database table Fruit
            dbFruitsToMatch.Add(ReturnFruitRow());

            IEnumerable<FruitClass> listComparer = checkIfFruitsMatch.Except(dbFruitsToMatch);
            foreach (FruitClass i in listComparer)
            {
                using (var db = new DBEntities())
                {
                    int countDBexisting = db.FruitTable.Where(x => x.Apples == i.Apples).Count();
                    if (countDBexisting > 0) 
                    {
                        //Fruit has been previously logged. No need to insert a duplicate
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LogFruitToDB(i, "spAddFruitsToDB"); //Insert records into a new table called "TableReport"
                    }
                }
            }

            work_book.Close();
            Excel_app.Quit();

        }


        private void LogFruitToDB(FruitClass fruitInstance, string cmdText)
            {
                myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
                {
                    mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, mySQLConnection);
                    mySQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter Apples_Parameter = new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@Apples",
                        Value = fruitInstance.Apples
                    };
                    mySQLCommand.Parameters.Add(Apples_Parameter);

                    SqlParameter Oranges_Parameter = new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@Oranges",
                        Value = fruitInstance.Oranges
                    };
                    mySQLCommand.Parameters.Add(Oranges_Parameter);

                    SqlParameter Pears_Parameter = new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@Pears",
                        Value = fruitInstance.Pears
                    };
                    mySQLCommand.Parameters.Add(Pears_Parameter);

                    SqlParameter Bananas_Parameter = new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@Bananas",
                        Value = fruitInstance.Bananas
                    };
                    mySQLCommand.Parameters.Add(Bananas_Parameter);

                    SqlParameter DateAddedUtc_Parameter = new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@DateAddedUtc",
                        Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
                    };
                    mySQLCommand.Parameters.Add(DateAddedUtc_Parameter);

                    mySQLConnection.Open();
                    mySQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

private FruitClass ReturnFruitRow()
{
    FruitClass fruitInfo = new FruitClass();
    myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
        string procedureName = "select * from dbo.FruitTable";
        mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand(procedureName, mySQLConnection);
        mySQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        mySQLCommand.Connection = mySQLConnection;
        mySQLCommand.Connection.Open();
        mySQLDataReader = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (mySQLDataReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (mySQLDataReader.Read())
            {
                fruitInfo.Apples = mySQLDataReader.GetString(1);
                fruitInfo.Oranges = mySQLDataReader.GetString(2);
                fruitInfo.Pears = mySQLDataReader.GetString(3);
                fruitInfo.Bananas = mySQLDataReader.GetInt32(4).ToString();
            }
        }
        mySQLCommand.Connection.Close();
    }
    return fruitInfo;
}

        private string CellToString(object p)
        {
            try
            {
                return ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)p).Value.ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }

    public class FruitClass
    {
        public string Apples;
        public string Oranges;
        public string Pears;
        public string Bananas;
    }
```

**Note:**   The `csv` file came in as a normal `.xlsx` excel file with columns then got saved as a `.csv`.

**Test.csv:** Shown below
[image]

So, say `FruitTable` had a matching record:
[image]

Then, `Table Report` should look like below when the program is finished:
[image]

But now real scenario has about 200 000 records. Also worth mentioning that this application is run once a month.

Comment: Can you share the sample of csv file you are trying to read,? There are other problems in your code but let's see the csv contents first

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I've just done so.

Comment: The problem is with the .csv. Why do you include the table and stopro definition?

Comment: @OleEHDufour For someone who wants to replicate my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are reading the .csv via interop.

You will gain a lot of time if you read the csv as a flat file subsequently manipulating its values.

see [Reading CSV file and storing values into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282999/reading-csv-file-and-storing-values-into-an-array)

Comment: In my scenario the csv data is not separated by semicolons. It is column based

Comment: But you could save it as such manually. I you wish do to so by interop see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034856/4180382

Comment: @Harold_Finch column separated is simply tab spaced, right?

Comment: @InBetween No, please see the screenshot which I just added to the question.

Comment: @Harold_Finch what I’m seeing is how excel opens and interprets the csv which has very little do to with what csv format you are dealing with. Open the file with a regular text editor and see what the separator is.

Comment: Okay, I see the output in the data is comma separated. If I may ask, why so much emphasis in how the file is opened? @InBetween

Comment: Because now you don't need interop ;-)

Comment: Opening file in excel is to make it more nicely visible and readable by human eye. But as a program what makes more sense how easily and faster it can be read. So if you can read the excel file as a CSV without using any complex logic it makes more sense.

Comment: It took me quite a while to understand what you guys were saying but I got a working solution and it's way faster now! Thanks

Comment: Good news that is Harold. Happy coding and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Your method will be very expensive in performance. I advise you another method:

1) Create a temp_report table that has the structure of the rows you want to put in your report table.

2) At the beginning of your program empty this new table

```
delete from dbo.temp_report
```

3) Get an empty datable yourdatatable with

```
DataTable yourdatatable = new DataTable();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection (connString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("select * from dbo.temp_report", conn);
conn.Open ();

// create data adapter
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter (cmd);

// this will be your datatable
da.Fill (yourdatatable);
conn.Close ();
```

4) Insert your csv lines into the datatable (c#)

```
for(here your loop on csv file)
{
    row = yourdatatable.NewRow();
    row["id"] = i;
    row["item"] = "item " + i.ToString();
    yourdatatable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

5) Send all your lines to the database using the bulk copy method:

```
using (SqlConnection destinationConnection = new SqlConnection (connString))
{
   destinationConnection.Open ();

   using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy (destinationConnection))
   {
       bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.temp_report";

       try
       {
           // Write from the source to the destination.
           bulkCopy.WriteToServer (yourdatatable);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
       }

   }
}
```

6) Insert into the TableReport table the rows that are not in the FruitTable table
by making a query that makes the difference (and not by C # code)

7) Note that you can also improve your performance by reading your csv file
text with a split on the separator (tab, or, depending on your file)