SSIS excel data source - how to force it to read as text?
I have an excel file with one column. It can have date or number or text.
In the ssis data flow task I use the Excel data source task to read the excel file, and then I store this into a SQL table column of type nvarchar(1000).
Now the problem seems to be that based on the first 8 values in the excel column, ssis dynamically detects the type. If it detects it as a number, then, when it reads the column it treats the text values as nulls.
I think the solution is to change something in the excel data source tasks advanced editor (external columns / input columns settings), but I can't figure this out regarding which setting to change. Can someone guide me with this.

It is possible to change registry entries to force excel to read the whole column in order to detect it's a mixed type, but this is often a challenge because of permissions and it would need to happen on the servers as well.  The better option would be to convert the excel file to csv and then import that.  You would do this via a script task, this is talked about here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034717/save-an-excel-file-to-a-csv-file-in-c-sharp-code

I'm not sure why is a simple thing like this not configurable in excel source task. I mean the advanced editor settings seem to be useless and confusing.
